# Minimal uncountable well-ordered set $S_{\Omega}$ is not compact

Tags: general-topology

In Munkre's Topology, he writes that

> Minimal uncountable well-ordered set $S_{\Omega}$ is not compact, since it has no largest element.

I know that $S_\Omega$ has no largest element, but how does that show $S_\Omega$ is not compact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you are talking about $\omega_1$ with the order topology.

Consider the family of open sets $\mathcal{O}=\{(a, b): a, b\in\omega_1\cup\{-\infty\}\}$.

- Does $\mathcal{O}$ cover $\omega_1$?
- If so, does it have a finite subcover?